# How do I retrieve rows in an sqlite3 database using prepared statements using datetime('now', '-1 day')?

Tags: c, sqlite, prepared-statement

Given a table designed like this:

```
CREATE TABLE calls(timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, callerid TEXT, contactid INTEGER)
```

If I want to extract all rows where the timestamp is within 1 day I can use this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM calls WHERE timestamp >= datetime('now', '-1 day');
```

In code using the unsafe convenience functions I could write this like so:

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg = 0;
int rc = sqlite3_open("mydb.db", &db);
const char* sql = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE timestamp >= datetime('now', '-1 day');";
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);
```

I would have to setup the callback function, of course, to handle retrieving the records.

But if instead I wanted to perform the same SELECT statement using a prepared statement how would I do that?

I tried like this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg = 0;
int rc = sqlite3_open("mydb.db", &db);

sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
const char* sql = "SELECT rowid,* FROM calls WHERE timestamp >= :timestamp;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":timestamp");
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, idx, "datetime('now', '-1 day')", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); break;

// but this while loop exits immediately - ie no data returned
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE) {
  // code here to extract field data
}

rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

But sqlite3_step returns SQLITE_DONE immediately, ie it returns no data.

How should I setup the calls to the prepared statement functions to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite's concatenation operator `||` to concatenate the named parameter `:days` which will be a string like `"-1"` inside the sql statement:

```
const char* sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM calls WHERE timestamp >= datetime('now', :days || ' day');";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":days");
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, idx, "-1", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

Or if you want to pass a string like `"-1 day"` with a named parameter `:period`:

```
const char* sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM calls WHERE timestamp >= datetime('now', :period);";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":period");
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, idx, "-1 day", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, are you retrieving `SQLITE_ROW`, which is the return code indicating that a new record is ready to be read, and is in fact different to `SQLITE_DONE` ?

According to the documentation of [sqlite3_step](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), and the [list of codes](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#done):

- `SQLITE_ROW`: The SQLITE_ROW result code returned by sqlite3_step() indicates that another row of output is available.
- `SQLITE_DONE`: The SQLITE_DONE result code indicates that an operation has completed. The SQLITE_DONE result code is most commonly seen as a return value from sqlite3_step() indicating that the SQL statement has run to completion.

Also, from `sqlite3_step`:

> If the SQL statement being executed returns any data, then SQLITE_ROW is returned each time a new row of data is ready for processing by the caller. The values may be accessed using the column access functions. sqlite3_step() is called again to retrieve the next row of data.